# swift 5 TextBox Value Display in Label

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am just creating a welcome screen wanted the user to input first name and after tapping the button it saves his name and print it out in the label

```
class userDataViewController: UIViewController {

    // first name user input
    @IBOutlet weak var firstUserInput: UITextField!
    
    // last name user input
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameInput: UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        var _: NSString? = firstUserInput?.text as NSString?
        var _: NSString? = lastNameInput?.text as NSString?
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your code? What's working? What's not working? In Swift 3+, avoid NSStuff and prefer Stuff when possible:` NSString` => `String`.

Comment: Where is your output label?

Comment: @Rob  how should I refer to that output label in code so I can display it as (welcome, the first name)